# Get multiple regex expressions working together to match complex set of strings

Tags: python, regex

I'm developing some code to extract all items from `ActiveSubInfoList` and those items are in between {}. Currently, I'm trying to create a regular expression to match the expected output. Below, you can find a sample text and desired output.

Sample text:

```
SubscriptionController:
 mLastISubServiceRegTime=1591226711086
 defaultSubId=43564
 defaultDataSubId=1
 defaultVoiceSubId=1
 defaultVideoSubId=-1
 defaultSmsSubId=1
 defaultDataPhoneId=456456
 defaultVoicePhoneId=65463456
 defaultSmsPhoneId=4562546
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 ActiveSubInfoList:
  {id=1, iccId=xxxxxxx simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=529 displayName=Claro BR carrierName=Claro }
  {id=2, iccId=yyyyyyyyy simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=530 displayName=Vivo carrierName=Vivo nameSource=1 }
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 AllSubInfoList:
  {id=1, iccId=kkkkkkkkk simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=529 displayName=Claro BR carrierName=Claro BR nameSource=1 }
  {id=2, iccId=uuuuuuuuu simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=530 displayName=Vivo carrierName=Vivo nameSource=1 }
2020-06-03T20:25:11.107 - [SubscriptionController] init by Context
2020-06-03T20:25:14.301 - [clearSubInfoRecord]+ iccId: slotIndex:0
2020-06-03T20:25:14.338 - [clearSubInfoRecord]+ iccId: slotIndex:1
2020-06-03T20:25:14.360 - [sendDefaultChangedBroadcast] broadcast default subId changed phoneId=ppp subId=bbb
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Sample output:

```
   Match 1: id=1, iccId=xxxxxxx simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=529 displayName=Claro BR carrierName=Claro 

   Match 2: id=2, iccId=yyyyyyyyy simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=530 displayName=Vivo carrierName=Vivo nameSource=1
```

What I have now are two separated regex:

One used to get all text between {}.

```
\{(.*?)\}


Match 1 id=1, iccId=xxxxxxx simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=529 displayName=Claro BR carrierName=Claro
Match 2 id=2, iccId=yyyyyyyyy simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=530 displayName=Vivo carrierName=Vivo nameSource=1
Match 3 id=1, iccId=kkkkkkkkk simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=529 displayName=Claro BR carrierName=Claro BR nameSource=1
Match 4 id=2, iccId=uuuuuuuuu simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=530 displayName=Vivo carrierName=Vivo nameSource=1
```

And this one that gets all text between `ActiveSubInfoList`  and `+`

```
(?s)(?<=ActiveSubInfoList).*?(?=\+)

:
{id=1, iccId=xxxxxxx simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=529 displayName=Claro BR carrierName=Claro }
{id=2, iccId=yyyyyyyyy simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=530 displayName=Vivo carrierName=Vivo nameSource=1 }
```

I'm struggling to get both those expressions working together to get the desired output.

Comment: One option is to use the PyPi regex module `(?:^[^\S\r\n]*ActiveSubInfoList:\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*{|\G(?!^){)([^{}]+)}[^{}]*` https://regex101.com/r/W87iQX/1

Comment: Your mentioned regex gives almost the same output as `\{(.*?)\}`.

Comment: Almost, only `\{(.*?)\}` will also match without `ActiveSubInfoList`

Comment: To get the matches between the last `+++++` line, you could add a positive lookahead https://regex101.com/r/Y9PZlD/1

Comment: Did that work out?

Comment: Nop, Actually the above expression only matches the first {id=1.

Comment: Please, refer to the Sample output in my comment. I did not find a nice solution for that yet.

Comment: Did you see the regex demo? You get 4 times group 1 which contains the values https://regex101.com/r/Y9PZlD/1

Comment: Please, see my answer for this question. It's not the ideal solution that I was pursuing, but it works. I would like to see a one-line solution to get all ActiveSubInfoList sim cards at once.

Comment: See [demo](https://tio.run/##tVNdT8IwFH12v6LuaeMr2/gwkixEiTFLkBiHvKxgxla0sWuXriMjk9@OhTEFQ4QHPS9t7j255/akJ16KN0ab6zWOYsYF4OgVZYoS@0IgToENuKr1ulNvCl3IIZ1UbgKBF8hNZw6dswFORBfyHqTfhPwD3mu9y6me65o3zVeTqr7anhWtZ3swge6kAims6qqiCJSIl0RwqaOpIERzPyVizHCAHuVWyAntTrvVabbaHUhV5eKL4kZJSZA9S3KKfvUEdlOOvKFogByHtlkDOAjk6KwASHDkEiYcGqLMrpsg8DnHiEtG27oGIU5i4i@HfoTsPvE5A7dPJWWvuNqXsEqJZYnfRJrGgcgYL9iBwLZA5c1lKQ@QbZZi59pByEkv3kv8jRuyeGzhH@6kJf7FHcuwjLrRqRvNkWV0rXbXNBumcQXqwJN2JAHHscCM9hkVnBGC@ARgigWYLcGmhjJxrssFb/PZVV1mi2MqtG3QGnNMQ58QbZe3GigTUSuS2Hh4HoycgTO80/X1@hM)

Comment: I had to shorted the content a bit or else the link was too long to paste in the comment box. Did you mean like that?

Comment: That works quite nicely! I can get 0, 1 index of your findall. But, if ActiveSubInfoList and AllSubInfoList are inverted? The output is going to be wrong.

Comment: Just tested it, I'm wrong.

Comment: Your solution works for both possibilities. Can you answer this question? I can accept your solution!!

Comment: I have posted it with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the multiple matches, you could make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

This allows you to make use of the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches.

```
(?:^[^\S\r\n]*ActiveSubInfoList:\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*{|\G(?!^){)([^{}]+)}[^{}]*(?=[\s\S]*\n\+)
```

- `(?:` Non capture group
- `^[^\S\r\n]*` Start of string followed by 0+ times a whitespace char except a newline

  - `ActiveSubInfoList:` Match literally
  - `\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*{` Match a newline, 0+ times a whitespace char except newline and `{`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^){` Assert the position at the previous match, not at the start of the string
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^{}]+` Match 1+ times any char except `{` or `}`
- `)` Close group
- `}[^{}]*` Match `}` and 0+ times any char except `{` or `}`
- `(?=[\s\S]*\n\+)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is a newline followed by a plus sign

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9PZlD/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##tVNdT8IwFH12v6LuaeMr2/gwkixEiTFLkBiHvKxgxla0sWuXriMjk9@OhTEFQ4QHPS9t7j255/akJ16KN0ab6zWOYsYF4OgVZYoS@0IgToENuKr1ulNvCl3IIZ1UbgKBF8hNZw6dswFORBfyHqTfhPwD3mu9y6me65o3zVeTqr7anhWtZ3swge6kAims6qqiCJSIl0RwqaOpIERzPyVizHCAHuVWyAntTrvVabbaHUhV5eKL4kZJSZA9S3KKfvUEdlOOvKFogByHtlkDOAjk6KwASHDkEiYcGqLMrpsg8DnHiEtG27oGIU5i4i@HfoTsPvE5A7dPJWWvuNqXsEqJZYnfRJrGgcgYL9iBwLZA5c1lKQ@QbZZi59pByEkv3kv8jRuyeGzhH@6kJf7FHcuwjLrRqRvNkWV0rXbXNBumcQXqwJN2JAHHscCM9hkVnBGC@ARgigWYLcGmhjJxrssFb/PZVV1mi2MqtG3QGnNMQ58QbZe3GigTUSuS2Hh4HoycgTO80/X1@hM)

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I came out with the following solution:

```
out= "Sample text from previous question"
active_sim_info = re.search(r"(?s)(?<=ActiveSubInfoList).*?(?=\+)", out, re.MULTILINE).group(0)
for sim in re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}", active_sim_info, re.MULTILINE):
    print(f">>>{sim}")
```

The output for that is:

```
>>id=1, iccId=xxxxxxx simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=529 displayName=Claro BR carrierName=Claro
>>id=2, iccId=yyyyyyyyy simSlotIndex=-1 carrierId=530 displayName=Vivo carrierName=Vivo nameSource=1
```